# How to search via character matching with a skip distance?

Tags: java, string, search, character

As the title says, I'm working on a project in which I'm searching a given text, moby dick in this case, for a key word. However instead of the word being linear, we are trying to find it via a skip distance ( instead of cat, looking for c---a---t).

I've tried multiple ways, yet can't seem to get it to actually finish one skip distance, have it not work, and call the next allowed distance (incrementing by 1 until a preset limit is reached)

The following is the current method in which this search is done, perhaps this is just something silly that I'm missing?

```
private int[] search()
throws IOException
{
        /*
         tlength is the text file length, 
         plength is the length of the
         pattern word (cat in the original post),
         text[] is a character array of the text file. 
         */

    int i=0, j;
        int match[] = new int[2];
        int skipDist = 2;
        while(skipDist <= 100)
        {
            while(i<=tlength-(plength * skipDist))
            {
                j=plength-1;

                while(j>=0 && pattern[j]==text[i+(j * skipDist)])j--;

                if (j<0)
                   {
                      match[0] = skipDist;
                      match[1] = i;
                      return match;
                   }


                else
                   {
                     i++;

                   }



            }
            skipDist = skipDist + 1;

        }
        System.out.println("There was no match!");
        System.exit(0);
        return match;
    }
```

Comment: Explain the variables tLength, pLength, pattern, text[].

Comment: tlength is the text file length, plength is the length of the pattern word (cat in the original post), text[] is a character array of the text file.

Comment: Do you want to find c...a...t with 0-3 other chars in between cat chars or exactly 3 chars? Do you want the string found or the index?

Comment: @Bohemian I'm looking for c..a..t with anywhere from 2 to a max skip distance (in the above code, trying for anywhere from 2 to 100). As soon as it finds one, It would return a match and stop searching.

Comment: the "match" that it's returning in the int array is the skip distance and the first character location of the matched word.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about the method you posted, but you can use this instead. I've used string and char array for this:

```
    public boolean checkString (String s)
{
    char[] check = {'c','a','t'};
    int skipDistance = 2;

    for(int i = 0; i< (s.length() - (skipDistance*(check.length-1))); i++)
    {
        boolean checkValid = true;
        for(int j = 0; j<check.length; j++)
        {
            if(!(s.charAt(i + (j*skipDistance))==check[j]))
            {
                checkValid = false;
            }
        }

        if(checkValid)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Feed the pattern to match in the char array 'check'.

String "adecrayt" evaluates true. String "cat" evaluates false.

Hope this helps.

*[This part was for fixed skip distance]*

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Now for any skip distance between 2 and 100:

```
    public boolean checkString (String s)
{
    char[] check = {'c','a','t'};
    int index = 0;
    int[] arr = new int[check.length];

    for(int i = 0; i< (s.length()); i++)
    {
        if(check[index]==s.charAt(i))
        {
            arr[index++] = i;
        }
    }
    boolean flag = true;

    if(index==(check.length))
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<arr.length-1; i++)
        {
            int skip = arr[i+1]-arr[i];
            if(!((skip>2)&&(skip<100)))
            {
                flag = false;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Skip Distance : "+skip);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        flag = false;
    }

    return flag;
}
```

Comment: Let me know if this was not what you were looking for. If it works, please do accept the response.

Comment: It semi works, however my output relies upon the search function returning both the final skip distance at which it found the word, as well as the character position of the first or last letter in the event of a match. And while yours does find it at a specific skip distance, I was hoping to have it able to "rotate" to the next skip distance in the event that 2 didn't find the chosen word

Answer (score 0):

If you pass in a `String`, you only need one line:

```
public static String search(String s, int skipDist) {
    return s.replaceAll(".*(c.{2," + skipDist + "}a.{2," + skipDist + "}t)?.*", "$1");
}
```

If no match found, a blank will be returned.